# Translate python for-loop function into R

Tags: python, r, for-loop, translate

I want to translate this python function into R. a is a list of numbers and the outcome should be 16/3. I appreciate any help!

```
def sum_differences(a):
    new_list = [abs(i-j) for i in a for j in a if i != j]
    outcome = sum(new_list) / len(a)
    return round(outcome,2)
```

This gives me 0:

```
sum_differences <- function(a){ 
  for (i in a){
    for (j in a){
        new_list <- abs(i-j)
        outcome <- sum(new_list) / length(a)
        return(round(outcome,2))
        }}}
```

a <- c(5, 3, 1)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I just did, it's literally a list of 3 values and the outcome should be 16/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a <- c(5, 3, 1)

sum_differences <- function(a) {
  new_list <- c() 
  
  for (i in a) {
    for (j in a) {
      if(i != j) {
        new_list <- c(new_list, abs(i-j))
      }
    }
  }
  outcome = sum(new_list) / length(a)
  return(round(outcome, 2))
}

sum_differences(a)

[1] 5.33
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know how I can do the same operation only taking unique values into consideration? e.g. a <- c(5, 3, 3, 1) only taking a <- c(5, 3, 1) because 3 appears twice

Comment: you can keep only unique in the vector:  `a <- unique(a)`

Comment: amazing, thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve this with `outer` -

```
a <- c(5, 3, 1)
sum(abs(outer(a, a, `-`)))/length(a)
#[1] 5.333
```

Or using a `for` loop -

```
outcome <- 0

for (i in a){
  for (j in a){
    new_list <- abs(i-j)
    outcome <- outcome + new_list
  }
}
outcome/length(a)
#[1] 5.333
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to directly translate it without simplifying it?

Comment: @Theresa_S Sure, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

We may also do this with `sapply`

```
a <- c(5, 3, 1)
sum(abs(sapply(a, `-`, a)))/length(a)
[1] 5.333333
```